# Broken QT5 packages are in release 14

Tags: package-management, qt5

Fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install.

Tried this on two different machines.

Same problem:

```
tstimac@promel:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential qmlscene qt5-qmake qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev qtdeclarative5-controls-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin libqt5qml-graphicaleffects qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
[sudo] password for tstimac: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5qml-graphicaleffects is already the newest version.
qtdeclarative5-window-plugin is already the newest version.
qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin is already the newest version.
qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin is already the newest version.
qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) but it is not going to be installed
 qt5-default : Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
 qtdeclarative5-dev : Depends: libqt5qml5 (= 5.2.1-3ubuntu15) but 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libqt5quick5 (= 5.2.1-3ubuntu15) but 5.2.1-3ubuntu15.1 is to be installed or
                               libqt5quick5-gles but it is not installable
                      Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```